# How to exclude a folder by name recursively when making a tar archive?

Tags: linux, backup, tar, gzip

I know it is possible to exclude a particular folder by a command like this:

```
tar --exclude='/srv/www/project/node_modules' -zcvf /backup/project.tgz .
```

My question how to exclude all folders named `node_modules` within the entire `/srv/www`?

Answer (score 0):

Use `\( ! -name node_modules \)` to omit this directory name from find's output.

The `-print0` option prints the full name of the file, followed by a null char. This should be used in case of filenames which contain newline chars.

The tar `-null` option primes the following `-T` option to read null-terminated files verbatim.

The tar `-T -` option reads files from stdin (the output from the pipe).

```
find . -type d \( ! -name node_modules \) -print0 | tar --null -czf /backup/project.tgz -T -
```